# How Task.ContinueWith should call another async method

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have two Async methods, one that makes an API call that gets an entity, and another that returns another entity dependent on the first one. For example, something like products and product categories in an REST API such as `GET /api/products/{productID}` returns a product that matches the ID and `GET /api/products/{productId}/category` returns the category of the product that matches the product ID.

In this case, we use the [method HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TValue>(HttpClient, String, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-8.0)
 twice, one for each call. Using the ContinueWith method, we basically end up with a Task of a Task (the type is `Task<Task<ProductCategory>>`).

Which approach is better?

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Json;

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

ProductCategory? category;


//  Use "await await"
category = await await httpClient
    .GetFromJsonAsync<Product>("https://apiexample.com/api/products/1234")
        .ContinueWith(task => httpClient
            .GetFromJsonAsync<ProductCategory>($"https://apiexample.com/api/categories/{task.Result?.CategoryId}"));

//  Use await and Task<TResult>.Result
category = await httpClient
    .GetFromJsonAsync<Product>("https://apiexample.com/api/products/1234")
        .ContinueWith(task => httpClient
            .GetFromJsonAsync<ProductCategory>($"https://apiexample.com/api/categories/{task.Result?.CategoryId}").Result);

//  Use unwrap and await
category = await httpClient
    .GetFromJsonAsync<Product>("https://apiexample.com/api/products/1234")
        .ContinueWith(task => httpClient
            .GetFromJsonAsync<ProductCategory>($"https://apiexample.com/api/categories/{task.Result?.CategoryId}"))
        .Unwrap();

//  Do not use ContinueWith at all
var product = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Product>("https://apiexample.com/api/products/1234");
category = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ProductCategory>($"https://apiexample.com/api/categories/{product?.CategoryId}");

Console.WriteLine(category);
Console.WriteLine("Done.");


class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string? ProductName { get; set; }
}

class ProductCategory
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string? CategoryName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"[CategoryID: {CategoryId}; CategoryName: {CategoryName}]";
}
```

Comment: `Which approach is better?` Which one do *you* think is more maintainable?

Comment: Is there any reason why do you prefer `ContinueWith` over `await`?

Comment: @PeterCsala It was because we were updating legacy code that was calling a synchronous method after a task was completed by using the ContinueWith method. Now the secondary method is asynchronous, which is why I was asking which way was the best way to call the secondary async function.

Answer (score 2):

I'll allow myself to quote [Async Guidance by David Fowler](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-await-over-continuewith):

> ### Prefer `await` over `ContinueWith`
>
> `Task` existed before the async/await keywords were introduced and as such provided ways to execute continuations without relying on the language. Although these methods are still valid to use, we generally recommend that you prefer `async`/`await` to using `ContinueWith`. `ContinueWith` also does not capture the `SynchronizationContext` and as a result is actually semantically different to `async`/`await`.
>
> ❌ **BAD** The example uses `ContinueWith` instead of `async`
>
> ```
> public Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
> {
>    return CallDependencyAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
>    {
>        return task.Result + 1;
>    });
> }
> ```
>
> ✅ **GOOD** This example uses the `await` keyword to get the >result from `CallDependencyAsync`.
>
> ```
> public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
> {
>    var result = await CallDependencyAsync();
>    return result + 1;
> }
> ```

So go with the last one - *"Do not use ContinueWith at all"*:

```cs
var product = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Product>("https://apiexample.com/api/products/1234");
category = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ProductCategory>($"https://apiexample.com/api/categories/{product?.CategoryId}");
```